# JavaFX assigning event handler to scene on key pressed

Tags: javafx, event-handling

When I run the debugger in Eclipse, when I press an alphabetical key or the command key, the event handler's handle method is called. However, when I press any arrow key, the handle method is not called. What could be wrong?

Here is a minimal reproducible example.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
​
public class Test extends Application {
​
    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
​
        VBox vbox = new VBox();

        Label welcome = new Label("Welcome to CST Man Adventures");
        Label survive = new Label("See how many rounds you can survive!");

        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        vbox.getChildren().add(welcome);
        vbox.getChildren().add(survive);

        Button start = new Button("Start Round");

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().add(start);
        hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Current round: 1"));
        vbox.getChildren().add(hbox);
​
        hbox.setTranslateY(100);
​
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 700, 800);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                    System.out.println();
                } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                    System.out.println();
                } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                    System.out.println();
                } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
                event.consume();
            }
        });
​
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.setTitle("CST Man Adventures");
        mainStage.show();
​
    }
​
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug; I don't have access to my full development environment at the moment, but it works fine on JavaFX 8, and fails to work as you describe on JavaFX 12 (on a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.15.2). I can't find any reference to it (but I didn't search too hard). I would recommend testing this on the latest JavaFX version (currently 14), and if it still fails, file a bug report if there isn't already one.

Comment: As a workaround, an event filter seems to work: `scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, /* event handler */);`. This suggests something somewhere is intercepting these events and consuming them.

Comment: might be the focustraversal that's intercepting (just guessing, not near my IDE)